# SwiftUI For Each Button in list - not working... sometimes

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have made a custom selection button view in SwiftUI for an app that is being developed. I cant for the life of me work out why sometimes the buttons don't do anything - It is always the last x number of buttons that don't work (which made me think it was related to the 10 view limitation of swift ui however, I've been told this isn't an issue when using a for each loop).

Sometimes it works as expected and others it cuts off the last x number of buttons. Although when it is cutting off buttons it is consistent between different simulators and physical devices. Can anybody see anything wrong here?

I am new to SwiftUI and so could be something simple...

````
    
    @EnvironmentObject var QuestionManager: questionManager
    
    var listItems: [String]
    @State var selectedItem: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader {geom in
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    ForEach(Array(listItems.enumerated()), id: \.offset){ item in
                        Button(action: {
                            if (selectedItem != item.element) {
                                selectedItem = item.element
                            } else {
                                selectedItem = ""
                                QuestionManager.tmpAnswer = ""
                            }
                            
                        }, label: {
                            GeometryReader { g in
                                Text("\(item.element)")
                                    .font(.system(size: g.size.width/22))
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                    .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                    .background(
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill((item.element == selectedItem) ? Color(.green) : .white)
                                            .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
                                            .border(Color.gray)
                                    ).scaledToFit()
                            }
                            .frame(width: geom.size.width*0.92, height: 45)
                        }).disabled((Int(QuestionManager.answers.year) == Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())) ? validateMonth(month: item.offset) : false)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geom.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Reviewing your code, on possibility could be that you are using `.enumerated()`. [Enumerated doesn't play well with a `ForEach](https://alejandromp.com/blog/swiftui-enumerated/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Yrb mentioned, using `enumerated()` is not a great option in a `ForEach` loop.
Your issue could be compounded by `listItems` having duplicate elements.
You may want to restructure your code, something like this approach using a dedicated
item structure, works very well in my tests:

```
struct MyItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name = ""
    
    init(_ str: String) {
        self.name = str
    }

    static func == (lhs: MyItem, rhs: MyItem) -> Bool {
       lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var QuestionManager: questionManager
    // for testing
    var listItems: [MyItem] = [MyItem("1"),MyItem("2"),MyItem("3"),MyItem("4"),MyItem("6"),MyItem("7"),MyItem("8"),MyItem("9")]
    
    @State var selectedItem: MyItem? = nil
     
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {geom in
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    ForEach(listItems){ item in
                        Button(action: {
                            if (selectedItem != item) {
                                selectedItem = item
                            } else {
                                selectedItem = nil
                                QuestionManager.tmpAnswer = ""
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            GeometryReader { g in
                                Text(item.name)
                                    .font(.system(size: g.size.width/22))
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                    .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                    .background(
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill((item == selectedItem) ? Color(.green) : .white)
                                            .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height)
                                            .border(Color.gray)
                                    ).scaledToFit()
                            }
                            .frame(width: geom.size.width*0.92, height: 45)
                        })
                      .disabled((Int(QuestionManager.answers.year) == Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())) ? validateMonth(item: item) : false)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geom.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func validateMonth(item: MyItem) -> Bool {
        if let itemOffset = listItems.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            // ... do your validation
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
   
}
```